# is it possible to make a smart intake form in community template

Tags: case, customer-community, lightning-community

I have a requirement to create an input form using customer service community template. I want to build a smart form e.g based on the value provided in Field A, the rest of the fields/few fields on the page appear or disappear (kind of what we do using javascript). Not really sure how to do these sort of things using community template. Also once the form is submitted, a case should be created in Salesforce. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this by creating a Lightning Component that you put into a community page. I would start by going through 
 https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics and https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/javascript-essentials-salesforce-developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Lightning Component with such a form, using aura:if statements to let parts of it appear or disappear. The case would then be created by the corresponding apex controller.

However, this approach requires some familiarity with Lightning Components.

(The same could be achieved via Visualforce Page, but I would recommend LC over VF.)